# Why doesn't .on() work for links that weren't preloaded on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After trying hashchange and finding out it simply doesn't work in Internet Explorer, I decided to try a click() approach instead.  What below is supposed to do is when a link is clicked, check to see if the url contains the page, then change the link_content's html to a div content with an id equal to the hash.

It works for all links that are preloaded with the page, but the current links in the link_content div do not trigger.  Why isn't this working?

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
    $('a').on("click", function(event){
        if (location.pathname.search("boh.html")){  
            hash=this.hash;
            if(hash=='#more'){
                $('#link_content').html($('#hiddenlist').html());
            }
            else if(hash){
                $('#link_content').html($(hash).html());
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {
    // Your function stuff
});
```

This is the delegation feature of the `on` method. It allows you to bind the event to a container element, but the callback function will only execute for elements designated by the selector you provide in the second parameter. Using `document` as the main selector for this scenario probably isn't the best (although it should work fine), and I think you should use:

```
$("#page_container").on("click", "a", function () {
```

Try to narrow down the main selector to a container element that you want this event to be bound to for its containing `<a>` elements. I guess even `"body"` could work, and I'm not sure which is preferred between `"body"` and `document`. Here's what I mean:

```
<body>
    <div id="main1">
        header stuff, no <a> elements
    </div>

    <div id="main2">
        main content, definitely contains <a> elements
    </div>
</body>
```

In this scenario, I would use `$("#main2").on("click", "a", function () {` because it narrows down the area where the event could occur (and hopefully reduces the processing by jQuery when a click event occurs).

Here's the `on` signature: http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject

The reason why this works is because the event is bound to the container, which is **not** (shouldn't be) dynamic and will always be available (and therefore the event will always be bound). When the specific event, "click" in your case, is triggered from an element inside the container, it bubbles up the container and that's where this event comes into play. The event will determine if the element that triggered the event matches the second parameter selector (if provided) and execute the event in its context if so.